# How can I generate cmap_cns.h in mupdf?

Tags: android, android-ndk, mupdf

I am compiling the MUPDF from NDK. I have created the "generated" folder under the "android" folder but its inner file which is expected to be autogenerated are not generating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I got the point. I am missing to execute `make` which I should execute after created `generated` folder and before executing `ndk-build`

Comment: hey....how can i use this make command can u explain ?boz i got error at compile time

Comment: Nice Answer,but I need your help regarding  text highlight in Mupdf Viewer.Any idea please tell me.Thanks